# MongoDB query and calculating average for nested array elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection `lanes` which has documents of following structure. Only the `dist` and `time` of new documents changes. I want to calculate average-speeds of all lanes grouped by `l_id`.

```
{
    _id: 1213,
    ab:[
        {
            l_id: 101,
            dist: 100,
            time: 100
        },
        {
            l_id: 102,
            dist: 140,
            time: 120
        },
        {
            l_id: 103,
            dist: 10,
            time: 10
        }
    ]
}
```

like this :

```
{[
    {
        l_id: 101,
        avgspeed: 14
    },
    {
        l_id: 102,
        avgspeed: 19
    },
    {
        l_id: 103,
        avgspeed: 9
    }
]}
```

How can it be done using mongo aggregate/unwind query?

EDIT 1: (how to do it the structure is as follows)

```
{
    _id: 1213,
    ab:[
        {
            l_id: 101,
            data:[{
                dist: 100,
                time: 100
            }]
        },
        {
            l_id: 102,
            data:[{
                dist: 140,
                time: 120
            }]
        },
        {
            l_id: 103,
            data:[{
                dist: 10,
                time: 10
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How you are calculating avgspeed?

Comment: something like this...
avgspeed = doc[0](dist)/doc[0](time) + doc[1](dist)/doc[1](time) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.Test2.aggregate([
   {
     $unwind: "$ab"
   },
   {
     $unwind: "$ab.data"
   },

   {
     $group:{
       _id: "$ab.l_id",
       avgspeed: {$avg:{$divide:["$ab.data.dist","$ab.data.time"]}}
     }
   }
]);
```

Comment: How would we do it if the documents structure is like shown in edited question?

Comment: Hey Daniele, there's a small mistake. 
`distance` should be the first argument and `time`, second.